# Checking a string condition stored in a variable with bit - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, bit

everyone!

I have a doubt: in my solution, the user is going to input some conditions based on existing variables, e.g:
 I have a table in wich I store the values of chemical analysis; this table has columns for all chemical elements involved in the process, with it's values for each event:

[See table here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDwIY.png)

Users can select any of this elements to compare with standard values in some sort of "parser", verifying "secure" standards every component has, in order to generate alarms when the condition goes out of regular, e.g.:

if fe > 10 and cr < 5 
   { //generate alarm}

My solution for this problem, until now,is to store the content of the condition as a string in a variable, replace the "names" of the elements for it's values for the analysis taken at that moment, and checking if the condition is true using a bit variable. So far, I was capable to do (the values are manually defined, so it was possible to remove the cursor and short the example):

```
`declare   @sql nvarchar(max)
         , @fe  int  
         , @sn int
         , @verifica bit

 set @fe = 59
 set @sn = 5

 set @sql =  'if fe > 50 and sn > 5'
 set @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'fe',@fe)
 set @sql =  +REPLACE(@sql,'sn',@sn)`
```

Result:

if 59 > 50 and 5 > 5

My question here is how to use the bit variable to check this condition (if it is even possible) or if I have to use it as a WHERE clause without replacing the values, e.g.:

```
 declare  @select nvarchar(max)
         ,@sql nvarchar(max)

 set @sql =   'fe > 50 and sn > 5'
 set  @select =  'select * from 'myAnalysisTable' where'+@sql
 exec @select
```

I prefer the first option because conditions can have any element users wants to use, sometimes with parentheses and more then one checking, and the replace solution solves the problem of string organization, being only necessary to check if current values are greater or less then the standard values - the "where-clause" solution would take just lot of work on making sure the statement is right stored to be parsed.

Can someone please help me?
I've seen the MIT parser solution on GitHub, but I'd like to develop my own, following the line of thought I had... is it possible?

Comment: It's really unclear to me why the second solution is less appealing to you, unless you just really have an itch write an expression parser.  Seems far easier to me to give the condition a quick check (especially for injection!!) and then let the SQL engine do the heavy lifting.  KISS.

Comment: Are you asking about something like `'select case when ' + @ConditionExpression + ' then Cast( 1 as Bit ) else Cast( 0 as Bit ) end'` to return a `Bit` value for one set of element criteria?